# Is there any difference between temp view and temporary view?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am learning sql using pyspark-sql. I just wanted to check if in some conditions the two lines given in the Code, in particular ('create or replace temporary view') and ('create or replace temp view') part can be different or they will always give same results?

These lines given as the code had same results and it make sense that there is no difference between temp and temporary view.

'''
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW myTempTable
  USING parquet
  OPTIONS (
    path "..."
  )
'''

'''
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW myTempTable
  USING parquet
  OPTIONS (
    path "..."
  )
'''

I will get same myTempTable for both lines. Is there any condition that I may get something different for these two lines?

Comment: I am not seeing "create or replace temp view" even existing ... docs here: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-view.html

Comment: But "create or replace temp view" is working for me